# Is there any way to convert a "bundled" MeteorJs source code to a normal source code?

Tags: meteor

I have a .tar.gz file of a MeteorJS application. This file was created using this command "meteor build --architecture=os.linux.x86_64 ./". I don't have original source code of this app because the author dev disappeared totally. Now I want to convert the .tar.gz file to a normal MeteorJS source code to add some changes (add third-party packages ...). So is there any way to do this? If not, is there any way to add new third-party packages to the app? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I think you probably can reconstruct it.

Looking at one of my projects, under

```
bundle/programs/server/app/app.js
```

This file is a concatenation of my source files. You could probably write a script to unpack this into separate files. I don't know if anyone has done it before, but it might be useful to post the tool when you have built it.

Comment: Thanks Mikkel. I know this trick. I just wonder if there is a tool for this kind of job.

Comment: Not that I know of, but a competent perl programmer could do it in an hour, or in fact it could be done in js with some regex work, because the principles are the same.